# ReportPortal in android project

Tags: android, android-studio, reportportal

I have the task to use reportportal in my current android project, but don't know how to implement it. I founded the link:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=j&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Freportportal%2Fagent-java-junit&uct=1531336394&usg=DbQWJ-ARJIdTcMujuDJZyI4NlFs

Which explain how to integreate reportportal to java-project with maven, but I haven't pow.xml and using gradle for build apk. Can you share with me link on tutorial or guide about how integrate reportportal in android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gradle.build files in repo as well.
use it for build process.

For other points - there is no difference.

RP listener should be integrated with junit runner, and stay agnostic to platform you use.